# List.Exists missing within Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, xamarin, portable-class-library

I am creating a Portable Class Library (PCL) and I am trying to use List.Exists() and List.TrueForAll(), but I am being told that System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain a definition for either Exists or TrueForAll. The PCL I am creating is to work across the .Net 4.5, Silverlight 4, Windows Phone 7.5, Mono Android, and Mono iOS. Is there something that I am missing?

Note: This code works in a .Net 4.0 Library which I have made.

Code Examples which return errors:

```
List<object> set0;
List<object> set1;

if (set0.TrueForAll(obj0 => set1.Exists(obj1 => obj0.Equals(obj1))))
    return true;

if(!(set0.Exists(obj0 => !set1.Exists(obj1 => obj0.Equals(obj1)))))
    return true;
```

Errors Recived:

> Error: 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Exists' and no extension method 'Exists' accepting a
>   first argument of type  'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Error: 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a
>   definition for 'TrueForAll' and no extension method 'TrueForAll'
>   accepting a  first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: They should be easily replacable by Linq's All and Any

Comment: [This documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx) claims (under _Version Information_) that the method is _Supported in: Portable Class Library_.

Comment: I found this document which has the libraries which one would have access to [PLIB APIs](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=8A7FB4A4B32FB2C9!180&app=Excel&authkey=!AHaBmLAhQ49YCI0). Am I completely off base with this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to determine, in a cumbersome way, if `set0` is a subset (mathematically) of `set1`. If you change your type from `List<>` to `HashSet<>` or `SortedSet<>`, you will get this functionality for free.

Otherwise, consider to use

```
set0.Except(set1).Any()
```

from Linq.

I'm not sure which methods exist in the Portable Class Library (PCL), but according to [the `List<>.Exists` doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx) this method does. And also the Linq methods I mentioned.

Comment: I do not have access to HashSet or SortedSet with in this PCL. Could there be an issue in the fact that my target frameworks are .Net Framework 4.5, Silverlight 4 and Higher, Window Phone 7.5, .Net for Windows Store Apps, Mono for Android, and MonoTouch?

Comment: @BlazePhoenix Do you have Linq? Try `using System.Linq;` and then `.Any` an so on. At the very least, stuff like `set1.Exists(obj1 => obj0.Equals(obj1))` should be changed to `set1.Contains(obj0)`.